# How to check two arrays of objects by propery id and if there is mach add property from one to anothe

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to compare two arrays of objects by `id` and then if `id`'s match add property `cr` with value to matching object in the array `arr`.

```
var arr = [{
    id: 1,
    username: 'fred'
}, {
    id: 2,
    username: 'bill'
}, {
    id: 3,
    username: 'ted'
}];

var arr1 =[{
    id:1,
    cr:1313
}, {
    id:2,
    cr:304
}];
```

I have searched for similar questions but could not find any or did not see that.

Comment: You're supposed to "program" not to "find answers". It is not alchemy.

Comment: Where does cr value come form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop on each array, compare their ids and if it's a match, assign your second object to your first one:

```
arr1.forEach(function(obj1) {
  arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (obj1.id === obj.id) {
      Object.assign(obj, obj1)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: No problem. If this solved your issue, consider chosing the answer, marking the post as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and assign the value to the hashed object.

```js
var arr = [{ id: 1, username: 'fred' }, { id: 2, username: 'bill' }, { id: 3, username: 'ted' }],
    arr1 = [{ id: 1, cr: 1313 }, { id: 2, cr: 304 }],
    hash = Object.create(null);

arr.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.id] = a;
});
arr1.forEach(function (a) {
    (hash[a.id] || {}).cr = a.cr;
});
    
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mckabue/s3bxu7u4/) on how to search in objects and arrays at the sometime, without necessarily knowing the depth of the object or array

```js
var o = {
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "arr":[1,2,3],
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]
};



//called with every property and it's value
function process(key,value,path) {
  var log = 'key: ' +key + ", value: "+value+", path: "+path;
    console.log(log);
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(log);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
}

function traverse(o,path,func) {
    for (var i in o) {
       
        if (o[i] !== null && typeof(o[i])=="object") {
            //going on step down in the object tree!!
            o[i].path = path+'/'+i;
            traverse(o[i],o[i].path,func);
        }else if(i !== 'path'){
         func.apply(this,[i,o[i], path+'/'+i]);  
        }
       
    }
}

//that's all... no magic, no bloated framework
traverse(o,'root',process);
```

```html
<ul id="myList">

</ul>
```